# Forge Viewer crash with non-ASCII chars in materials

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I recently came across a problem with the Autodesk Forge viewer (or should I call it the A360 viewer? Still not clear to me).

I used the model derivative API to translate a RVT file to SVF, being the suitable format for visualization, then retrieved all files locally (a lot like [extract.autodesk.io](https://github.com/cyrillef/extract.autodesk.io) actually) so I can feed them to the viewer.

For one of my RVT files, I had a problem when loading a 3D view :

```
SyntaxError: JSON.parse: bad control character in string literal at line 1296 column 33 of the JSON data
```

Doing my investigations, I found out the problem comes from  ProteinMaterials.json.gz, which for this translation contains a non-ASCII chars (i.e. Materials names and descriptions) including one at line 1296. Removing the character causes the error to move to the next non-ASCII, and so on.

Is there a workaround for this problem, other than asking users to remove non-ASCII chars from their RVT files?

Answer (score 0):

Call it the Forge Viewer  :-)

Question: does the problem appear when you feed the unmodified files directly into the viewer?

I hope not. Otherwise, many others would be raising a similar complaint.

Conclusion: you need to escape the non-ASCII characters in the JSON yourself.

When you feed the files directly into the viewer, some step in the workflow does it for you.

When you store them locally, you need to explicitly perform this step yourself.

Does that make sense?

Can you confirm?

Thank you!

Comment: Well the problem also occurs when I try using [Autodesk's viewer page](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/), so I'm not sure the problem lies in my end. Regardless, I will try your suggestion.

Comment: So, I can confirm you, even when I feed the viewer with the file URN, I encounter the exact same problem. If it's any help, I can provide a link to a "broken" viewer.

Comment: Here is the [link](https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/#id/dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6YTM2MHZpZXdlci90MTQ4NTE4NTIwMzMxMV8wMDczMTQ5MjgxMTc3NjM2M18xNDg1MTg1MjAzMzEyLnJ2dA?designtype=)

Comment: thank you! what do i do with it? how can i reproduce the problem, please? thx.

Comment: You don't have to do anything to reproduce the problem, it happens every time on load. You should see the lack of (or rather, not see) materials and visual constructs.
In browser console, the error message I mentioned in my post is present.

Comment: the devteam took a look and can reproduce the problem. can you also provide the RVT seed file for further analysis? thank you!

Comment: Sure, can you give me an email address where I can send it?

Comment: sure, you can send it directly to me jeremy dot tammik at autodesk dot com.  can you minimise it as much as possible, please? i guess it need not contain many elements... probably all but a very few can simply be deleted. if it is too big, please put it into a dropbox folder somewhere and give me a link to that. thank you!

Comment: thank you for the file. i attached it to the internal development issue REVIT-107955 [Non-ascii characters in ProteinMaterials in RVT files] and notified the development team.

Comment: Any update on the matter? I would very like to know if there is a public place where we could see forge roadmap and/or open issues. Do you think this will be resolved with v2.14?

Comment: REVIT-107955 [Non-ascii characters in ProteinMaterials in RVT files] has been closed and succeeded by REVIT-108682 [Non-ascii characters in ProteinMaterials in RVT files]. It is marked as critical and is still open. I added your query and notes to that and will let you know when I hear anything back from the devteam.

Comment: I've come yet again to ask you if any progress was made. I've found a workaround on my end (i.e. asking explicitly users to stop using non-ascii chars) but I'm still interested in the resolution process.

Comment: Very glad to hear you can manage with the workaround for the time being! I asked the development team once again... no news so far...